# qlabel mailto link in Qt 4.8.6

Tags: c++, qt

I've followed instructions given on previous questions like [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/22841/solved-qlabel-used-as-email-address/3)

so now if I put a link to a regular page it opens fine with the default browser. But if I want to open a mailto link from QT QLabel 4.8.6 the link does nothing.
What am I doing wrong?

here is the code:

```
UpgradeMessageDialog* umd = new UpgradeMessageDialog();
umd->ui->label->setOpenExternalLinks(true);
umd->ui->label->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextBrowserInteraction);
umd->ui->label->setText("<a href='mailto:user@foo.com?subject=Test&body=Just a test'>My link</a>");
umd->exec();
umd->ui->label->connect(umd->ui->label,
    SIGNAL(linkActivated(const QString&)), umd,
            SLOT(linkOpen(const QString&)));
```

(this is defined as a public slot in the appropriate h file)

```
void UpgradeMessageDialog::linkOpen(const QString &link)
{
    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(link));
}
```

Just to clarify: I have a default mail program set up in my computer, and when I type mailto:a@b.c in the browser that program opens fine.

Comment: Have you tries somethin simplier? like `<a href='mailto:user@foo.com'>email someone</a>`?

Comment: yes. same behavior.

Comment: And what does `QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("mailto:user@foo.com"));` ?

Comment: doesn't work as well. I'm using win10.

Comment: It's probably a bug, you should test with a more recent version of Qt (5.8)

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use Qt 4.8.6 for this project.

Comment: Sure, but give it a try with a simple project, if 5.5 fails, you must to the things the bad way, if it works, it confirms you it's a Qt 4.8 bug and then it's very likelly that you will not be able to have those links work in your project untill you upgrade Qt.

Comment: If the `QDesktopServices::openUrl(...)` mentioned @jpo38 doesn't work then probably you have a problem with the configuration of your default email composer too.

Comment: Where can I check these configurations? also, the openUrl returns 0 with a mailto address and 1 with an http address(it works there)

Answer (score 5):

First, there are two ways to handle link activation in QLabel. You should use one of them, but I see you are trying to use both.

This two ways are:

- Call `openExternalLinks(true)`, so that QLabel will automatically open links using `QDesktopServices::openUrl()` **instead** of emitting the `linkActivated()` signal.
- Connect to the `linkActivated()` signal and then manually open link in the connected slot (by calling `QDesktopServices::openUrl()` for example).

Also you use the `exec()` function wrong. You should put the `exec()` call after the `connect()` call, because `exec()` is blocking so the signal connection will actually happened after the dialog is closed.

So your code should be like this:

```
umd->ui->label->setText("<a href='mailto:user@foo.com?subject=Test&body=Just a test'>My link</a>");
connect(umd->ui->label, SIGNAL(linkActivated(QString)), umd, SLOT(linkOpen(QString)));
umd->exec();
```

or like this:

```
umd->ui->label->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
umd->ui->label->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextBrowserInteraction);
umd->ui->label->setOpenExternalLinks(true);
umd->ui->label->setText("<a href='mailto:user@foo.com?subject=Test&body=Just a test'>My link</a>");
```

And a little advise: put the label initialization code into the `UpgradeMessageDialog` constructor.

```
UpgradeMessageDialog::UpgradeMessageDialog(QDialog* parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
  ui->label->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
  ui->label->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextBrowserInteraction);
  ui->label->openExternalLinks(true);
  ui->label->setText("<a href='mailto:user@foo.com?subject=Test&body=Just a test'>My link</a>");
}
```

And then you can use your dialog this way:

```
QScopedPointer<UpgradeMessageDialog> umd = new UpgradeMessageDialog;
umd->exec();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I've tried both methods separately (signal/no signal) and still no results. Is there any place where one can check where is the mailto directed to?

Comment: @jreing, maybe your default mail client can't deal with mailto links with spaces? Try to change body to 'Test' instead of 'Just a test'

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <QUrl>
#include <QDesktopServices>

myLabel = new QLabel(this);
myLabel->setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);
myLabel->setText("Email:href='mailto:serge@essetee.be'>serge@essetee.be</a>");
myLabel->setOpenExternalLinks(true);
```

Now you just have to click the link and the standard mail client will be launched.